# Issue with elastic docker 6 images startup

Tags: elasticsearch, minikube

Tring to run elastic helm according to this link:
https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch

But the pod doesn't start due to an issue of global state.

Tried several versions and version 7 works fine.
`Images 6.7.1,6.5.0,6.6.1` doesn't work.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected field [cluster_uuid_committed]
>       at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData$Builder.fromXContent(MetaData.java:1270) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
>       at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData$1.fromXContent(MetaData.java:1300) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
>       at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData$1.fromXContent(MetaData.java:1291) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
>       at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.read(MetaDataStateFormat.java:196) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]

Pod should go up with no issue.

Comment: Is it possible that in the same cluster/network is an Elasticsearch 7 instance running? It seems that this field was introduced in 7 (see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/37775)

Comment: It seems that some PVs were still there - I deleted the PVs and now it works. the issue is solved. thanks!